# Is the symmetric group $S_4$ cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

> **Is the symmetric group $S_4$ cyclic?**

By writing all $24$ elements we can write the tabular form of $S_4$. Then choosing each element of $S_4$, we can find its order and thus, we can show that that there is no element of $S_4$ of order 24. Then $S_4$ will be non-cyclic.

But this is a laborious work as $S_4$ has $24$ elements. Is there any other way to show this?

Comment: Is $S^4$ even abelian?

Comment: Excellent point, @John Ma

Comment: There are even no elements of order $6$ in $S_4$...

Comment: @JohnMa Please answer both the questions (me & you)

Comment: See also more general question: [Are there any Symmetric Groups that are cyclic?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196361/are-there-any-symmetric-groups-that-are-cyclic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, if $S^4$ is abelian, then every subgroup is abelian, but $S^3\leq S^4$ and $S^3$ is the very first and unique (up to isomorphism) non-abelian group. $S^3$ in $S^4$ is $\langle(1234),(12)\rangle$.